# Problems with my PHP form on Github

Tags: php, html

I am trying to create a form for my website that is hosted on Github, when I press the submit button I see a page that says: The request made was to forbidden content. What could I be doing wrong?

HTML:

```
<form method="post" action="index.php">

<label>Name</label>
<input name="name" placeholder="Type Here">

<label>Email</label>
<input name="email" type="email" placeholder="Type Here">

<label>Message</label>
<textarea name="message" placeholder="Type Here"></textarea>

<label>*Wat is 2+2? (Anti-spam)</label>
```

```
<input id="submit" name="submit" type="submit" value="Submit">
```

PHP:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

    <?php
        $name = $_POST['name'];
        $email = $_POST['email'];
        $message = $_POST['message'];
        $from = 'From: insert'; 
        $to = 'placeholder@placeholder.com'; 
        $subject = 'Iemand heeft een bericht achter gelaten..';
        $human = $_POST['human'];

        $body = "From: $name\n E-Mail: $email\n Message:\n $message";

        if ($_POST['submit'] && $human == '4') {                 
            if (mail ($to, $subject, $body, $from)) { 
            echo '<p>Jouw bericht is verstuurd!</p>';
        } else { 
            echo '<p>Er is iets fout gegaan, probeer het later opnieuw.</p>'; 
        } 
        } else if ($_POST['submit'] && $human != '4') {
        echo '<p>Het antwoord op de vraag is onjuist!</p>';
        } else {
            echo '<p>Graag alle velden invullen!</p>';
        }
    ?>

    </body>
    </html>
```

The index and index php files are in the same directory

Comment: Are you expecting Github to be acting like a server where you can run your code?

Comment: You are not closing your form maybe?

Comment: The closing tag is not displayed but it is closed, it will be hosted on Github when it is finished so are you trying to say that Github does not support it or?..

Comment: _are you trying to say that Github does not support it or..._ Do you actually know what Github is?

Comment: I only use github to host my website on it, care to explain what is wrong with my question and why it's self-explaining why it does not work?

Comment: _I only use github to host my website..._ GitHub is a Git repository hosting service.. you don't host websites on it...

Comment: I'll try to find a non PHP form method then, thanks